# How to update another column based on Regex match in a different column in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a column say A with strings and another column B with binary values 1/0.
I am trying to match a regular expression in column A and update column B accordingly.

If this is my regular expression

```
pattern_1 = re.compile(r'\bstudent', re.IGNORECASE)
```

I would like the table to look like below.

```
A                    B
I am a teacher       0
I am a student       1
Student group        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pandas to create dataframe and make new column by checking each row data:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
pattern_1 = re.compile(r'\bstudent', re.IGNORECASE)
data = [['I am a teacher',0],['I am a student ',0],['Student group', 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['A','B']) 
print("orginal df:",df)
df['B'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if pattern_1.search(row.A) else row.B , axis=1)
print("\n\nmodified df:",df)
```

output:

```
orginal df:                  A  B
0               I am a teacher  0
1              I am a student   0
2                Student group  0

modified df:                  A  B
0                I am a teacher  0
1               I am a student   1
2                 Student group  1
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me how I can update an already existing column? I want to update only '1' for the cases where there is a match and if it is not a match I don't want to update the field and want to keep it as it was before. Basically is there any way I can avoid the 'else' part in your code.

Comment: I have edited my answer assuming that initially all your data of column B was 0. Then change only to 1 if condition matches

Comment: Hello, this code replaces the already existing 1s with 0. However it is successfully recognizing the pattern, updates as 1s and existing 0s are being kept as they are. Could you tell me why there could be a problem with existing 1s.

Comment: the updated code will not replace a 1 with 0 , it will search for pattern if pattern is found then it will write 1, and if not found it will not changed the value of column B

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how your columns are stored, but this sounds like a job for a basic for-loop with enumerate.
Assuming that A and B are lists:

```
for i, a_value in enumerate(A):
  B[i] = bool(pattern_1.search(A))
```